# When not authorized always return a 401

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

When not authorized I want to always return a 401, currently this only happens when I go to a path that is exists. 
How do I make it so that when I go to a path that doesn't exist it also returns a 401.

Note: I am currently using only 1 custom authentication handler that implements `AuthenticationHandler<T>`.

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services
         .AddMvc (options =>
         {
             var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder ().RequireAuthenticatedUser ().Build ();
             options.Filters.Add (new AuthorizeFilter (policy));
         })
         .SetCompatibilityVersion (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

     services
         .AddAuthentication (options =>
         {
             options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CustomAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticationScheme;
             options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CustomAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticationScheme;
         })
         .AddScheme<TicketAuthenticationOptions, CustomAuthenticationHandler> (CustomAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticationScheme, null);
 }

 public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
     app.UseAuthentication ();
     app.UseMvc ();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in whether or not the user is *authenticated*, you could add a custom middleware to the pipeline that converts a 404 into a 401. Here's a simple example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        await next();

        if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The custom middleware sits in front of the MVC middleware, waits for *that* to run and then converts the 404 into a 401 if the user has not been authenticated.